# Coerce a numpy array scalar to a particular C type using numpy C API

Tags: numpy, python-c-api

I have a PyObject* representing a numpy scalar array and I would like to check whether I can coerce the value to a float and then, if so, pull out a C float. I've been through the numpy C api docs in some detail but have not managed to do this.

Comment: Are you aware of [PyArray_CanCoerceScalar](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html#PyArray_CanCoerceScalar) and [PyArrayCastScalarToCtype](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/c-api.array.html#PyArray_CastScalarToCtype) and want a use example, or have you missed them in the documentation?

Comment: Yup I found those and was hoping for an example -- PyArray_CanCoerceScalar seems to be what I want but it wasn't clear to me how to set up the PyArray_Descr parameter for a given C type.

Answer (score 0):

One possible approach, as suggested in  http://shitohichiumaya.blogspot.in/2012/01/passing-user-defined-python-object-to-c_4561.html
is to check for the existence of a `__float__` attribute. E.g.

```
bool convertible_to_float(PyObject* obj_ptr)
    PyObject_HasAttrString(obj_ptr, "__float__")
```

This corresponds to the builtin function `float` at the Python interpreter level, and tells you whether it is convertible to the regular Python `float` type.

[Built-in Types -> Numeric Types](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#typesnumeric)
says

> Floating point numbers are usually implemented using double in C;
>   information about the precision and internal representation of
>   floating point numbers for the machine on which your program is
>   running is available in sys.float_info.

Thus, one can convert from a Numpy scalar array to Python float to C double to C float. It is probably possible to convert a
Python float to a C float directly. HTH.